# Date Ranges in Mondrian

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

I want to fetch data for TimeStamp t1 to t2. But t1 and t2 might not necessarily in my database table. So, what i want is: it should find next available timestamp greater than or equal to t1 ( > t1 in case t1 is not there in db table or t1 if it is there) and last available timestamp less than or equals to t2  ( < t2 if t2 is not there or t2 if it is there in db) in MDX query itself.

.FirstSibling, .LastSibling, .FirstChild, .LastChild, .NextMember, .LastMember, HEAD, TAIL won't work for me as i want timestamp be to >= t1 and <= t2 (with both available in db).
How should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling with dates in this way with MDX can be a pain. I have done similar things in the past by converting a `Name` or `Caption` to a string/number/date, and comparing it with your input parameters t1 and t2 (similarly converted to string/number/date in same format).

Perhaps t1 is a string "31/12/2010" and your cube contains members such as [Time].[All Time].[2010].[December].[29] then you will need to convert both into a common format to be compared. MDX provides methods such as `MemberToStr()` which will give you a string representation of the `.CurrentMember` and let you compare the two.

VBA functions can be used in some flavours of MDX, so you can manipulate strings with `Replace` and `InStr`, and even call functions such as `CDate()` to get a value which is in the same form as your input parameter.

You final MDX might look something like this...though I have greatly simplified the manipulation required to get the member's Caption into a string that the CDate function will accept:
`SELECT

{Filter({[Time].[Day].members}, CDate([Time].CurrentMember.Caption) <= CDate("2010-12-31"))} ON ROWS,

[Measures].[Something] ON COLUMNS

FROM [CubeName]`

The ROWS clause is first taking a set of all [Time] members at the [Day] level, and then filtering down that set to leave only those where the Caption (converted to a date object) is less than or equal to your input string (converted to a date object).